# mypy and pyproject.toml, options only work globally

Tags: mypy, pyproject.toml

I wish to use the options `disable_error_code = ["name-defined"]` and `ignore_missing_imports = true` only for some specific modules, but I am struggling to make it work.
The following is an excerpt of my non-working `pyproject.toml` file:

```ini
[tool.mypy]
python_version = "3.9"
disallow_untyped_defs = true
show_error_codes = true
no_implicit_optional = true
warn_return_any = true
warn_unused_ignores = true
exclude = ["scripts", "docs", "test"]


[[tool.mypy.overrides]]
module = [
    "firstmodule",
    "secondmodule",
    "utils",
    "config",
]
disable_error_code = ["name-defined"]
ignore_missing_imports = true
```

More specifically, if I keep `disable_error_code = ["name-defined"]` as indicated above, then I get the following kind of errors:

> pyproject.toml: [module = "utils"]: Per-module sections should only specify per-module flags (disable_error_code)

If I keep `ignore_missing_imports = true` as indicated above, then it is ignored and errors due to missing import are signaled.

If instead I move the mentioned two options under `[tool.mypy]` everything works.

Answer (score 21):

I also wanted to selectively disable warnings for packages that don't yet have type hints, and this approach seems to work for me:

```ini
[[tool.mypy.overrides]]
module = "firstmodule.*"
ignore_missing_imports = true

[[tool.mypy.overrides]]
module = "secondmodule.*"
ignore_missing_imports = true
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff, perhaps you can accept this answer @Barzi2001 ? This worked for me. I was getting `module is installed, but missing library stubs` for a particular range of modules. Using `[tool.mypy-azureml.*]` was being rejected from the `pyproject.toml`. Mypy documentation mentions `pyproject.toml` as a valid config source but studiously ignores what syntax can be used to support module-specific sections. Perhaps they want to discourage use of `pyproject.toml`. I added an overrides section as Jeff describes with `module = "azureml.*"` in that section and `ignore_missing_imports` was respected.

Answer (score 10):

I found that I could use a single `[[tool.mypy.overrides]]` section with a comma-separated list of package names, when disabling missing import warnings - e.g.

```ini
[[tool.mypy.overrides]]
module = "firstmodule.*,secondmodule.*"
ignore_missing_imports = true
```

Answer (score 1):

Up to now, there are too many options that are only supported globally. Amongst them, `disable_error_code`. In particular, it will warn you that

`Per module sections should only specify per-module flags`

Sources:

- [Per module and global options](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config_file.html?highlight=Per%20module%20sections%20should%20only%20specify%20per-module%20flags#per-module-and-global-options)
- [disable_error_code description](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config_file.html?highlight=disable_error_code#confval-disable_error_code)

Comment: can you provide a source?

Comment: @BartekLachowicz [Per module and global options](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config_file.html?highlight=Per%20module%20sections%20should%20only%20specify%20per-module%20flags#per-module-and-global-options) - [disable_error_code](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config_file.html?highlight=disable_error_code#confval-disable_error_code)

Comment: Thanks! @gabopushups. OOC how many push ups can you do at once?